# Elasticsearch scoring based on how close a number is to a query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to score my documents based on on how close a number is to a query. Given I have two documents `document1.field = 1` and `document2.field = 10`, a query  `field = 3` then I want `document1._score > document2._score`. Or in other words I want something like a fuzzy query against number. How would I achieve this? The use case is I want to support price queries (exact or range), but want to rank stuff that isn't exactly in the boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be implemented using [custom_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query/) query where script will determine boost depending on absolute value of the difference between exact price and desired price. The desired price should be passed to the script as a parameter to avoid script recompilation for every request.

Alternatively, it can be implemented using [custom_filters_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query/) query. Filters here will contain different ranges around desired price. Smaller ranges will have higher boost and appear higher in the list than larger ranges.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [Decay functions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay):

> Decay functions score a document with a function that decays depending on the distance of a numeric field value of the document from a user given origin. This is similar to a range query, but with smooth edges instead of boxes.