# how to find the nearest / closest number using Query DSL in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i am looking for a possibility to find the nearest price / number with the help of elasticsearch. the problem is that i do not have a range.
what i want to achieve is that the results are sorted by nearest distance. according to the example search query my index contains 3 documents with the following prices (numbers): 45, 27, 32

the "distance" from my search value 29 for the given numbers are 
45 - 29 = 16 | 27 - 29 = -2 | 32 - 29 = 3 so what i would expect is that the search results are scored by the "distance" the number is away from the given price.

search query example:

```
GET myawesomeindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "description": "this is the text i want to find"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "price": 29
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

i think my question is related to this similar question: [Elasticsearch scoring based on how close a number is to a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880103/elasticsearch-scoring-based-on-how-close-a-number-is-to-a-query)

Comment: That post you referenced is giving you the actual answer. What's wrong with that?

Comment: it "just" links to the elasticsearch reference but does not provide an example :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go:

```
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": "return doc['price'].value-distance",
      "params": {
        "distance": 29
      },
      "lang": "groovy",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
```

And you need to enable [dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).

You can, also, do it like this

```
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "description": "this is the text i want to find"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "price": 29
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "exp": {
            "price": {
              "origin": "29",
              "scale": "1",
              "decay": 0.999
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But this will alter the `score` itself. If you want pure sorting by the distance (and nothing else) then I believe the first option is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. In this example I'm using a timestamp in UTC seconds.

```
{
    "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "linear": {
                   "timestamp" : {
                        "origin": 1601227629,
                        "scale": "30m"
                   }
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode" : "multiply",
         "boost_mode": "multiply",
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         }
      }
   },
    "size": 1
}
```