# Elasticsearch in Python. How to get closes integer from search

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, integer, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using elasticsearch on a large indexed database. One of the queries requires to find an integer value and a string such as:

```
s = Search(using=es, index="index1").extra(size=500) \
                        .query("match_phrase", name={"query": "john".casefold()})\
                        .query("match", age="46")
```

This will search for a data record that contains "John white" and "46". However, If the age is not correct, I would like to get a record that contains "John white" and age that is the closest to "46" (assuming I have those records, otherwise it will return nothing).

The above query however only returns records of age EXACTLY "46".

A similar question already exists on SO: [how to find the nearest / closest number using Query DSL in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005785/how-to-find-the-nearest-closest-number-using-query-dsl-in-elasticsearch)

But I am not sure how to incorporate the JSON in my query since I am using specific python modules.

A case in point is the fact that I can use fuzziness on a string. But I think fuzziness on an integer is not possible in the same manner in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using script based sorting to accomplish this, as described here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting

Working under the assumption that you're only matching on the first name - if you want to match the name exactly, I'd recommend using a filter based match.  I used three different 'users' in the index, defined as follows:

```
POST index1/_doc
{
  "name": "John White",
  "age": 46
}

POST index1/_doc
{
  "name": "John White",
  "age": 40
}

POST index1/_doc
{
  "name": "John Black",
  "age": 47
}
```

I find it easier to write something a little more complex like this using Kibana's Dev Tools for testing, and then convert it to the Python Elasticsearch DSL compatible format - so in Kibana, I ultimately came up with the following:

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": {
        "query": "john"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "Math.abs(doc['age'].value - params.target_age)",
        "params": {
          "target_age": 46
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Note using the absolute value of the difference will give you the closest value in either direction (i.e. younger or older).  Some tweaks might be necessary if your requirements are different.  Simply adjust the parameter as your queries change to accommodate different target ages.

Once tested and validated, converting to Python Elasticsearch DSL is quite easy - you can use the 'Auto Indent' function to flatten the complexity of the `sort` and drop it right into your existing statement.

```
s = Search(using=es, index="index1").extra(size=500) \
    .query("match_phrase", name={"query": "john".casefold()}) \
    .sort({"_script":{"type":"number","script":{"lang":"painless","source": \
    "Math.abs(doc['age'].value - params.target_age)", \
    "params":{"target_age":46}},"order":"asc"}})
```

Executing this returns the expected response:

```
<Response: [<Hit(index1/_doc/VR3e7WkBsHIsqLp6vfx_): {'name': 'John White', 'age': 46}>, <Hit(index1/_doc/Vx3f7WkBsHIsqLp6DPxM): {'name': 'John Black', 'age': 47}>, <Hit(index1/_doc/Vh3e7WkBsHIsqLp6yfxd): {'name': 'John White', 'age': 40}>]>
```

However, as you indicated you want the *closest* value, I'd recommend changing the size parameter to `1`.

Comment: By closest value, I meant that if query wants "46" and data only contains "40" and "47", the first result it gives me (cause it has the highest score) would be "47". For example, if in your query, the target age is, say  "45", what would the search return s the highest score? I am emphasizing the score because for me is important having the highest score be the closest age value to the query. just sorting the returned responses is not enough.

Comment: @user7331538 The example query is solely focusing on finding the closest age along with whatever query is provided in your `match_phrase` clause; the actual `_score` value is not taken into account.

So to answer your question, using my query, if the `match_phrase` hits on `john`, and 2 results are returned with ages 40 and 47 with a target age of 45, the value of 47 is going to be returned as the top result.